# Cannot find object in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Banking[] Array with a limit of 100 (101) objects, a user creates an account and their account is inserted as an object into the array, when they want to log in the little method at the bottom runs to look for their account however it can never find the object. I'm not sure why, any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banking[] uaccounts;
        uaccounts = new Banking[100]; // setting up array
        int arrcount = 0; // setting counter for array
        int menu = 1;   // Creating a variable to loop menu
        while (menu == 1) {  //Creating the loop for the menu
            System.out.println("|=================================================|");     // drawing the menu
            System.out.println("|                                                 |");
            System.out.println("|                     MAIN MENU                   |");
            System.out.println("|  1. Create Account (BANK MANAGER RESTRICTED)    |");
            System.out.println("|  2. Check Account Balance                       |");
            System.out.println("|  3. Deposit Into Account                        |");
            System.out.println("|  4. Withdraw From Account                       |");
            System.out.println("|  5. Quit                                        |");
            System.out.println("|                                                 |");
            System.out.println("|=================================================|");

            int uinput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select an option from above(1 - 4):"));
            if (uinput == 1) {    // initiating menu option 1
                String full_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter clients full name:");     // creating some variables
                String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the clients address:");
                String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the clients password:");
                int accid = RandomInt(100000, 999999);
                System.out.println("Customers Account ID:" + accid);
                double balance = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the client's starting balance:"));
                uaccounts[arrcount] = new Banking(full_name, address, accid, balance, password); // creating objectg in array
                arrcount = arrcount + 1; //adding to counter for next time

            }
            if (uinput == 2) {     // initiating menu option 2
                int acc_id_input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account ID:"));
                String password_input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your password:");
                int arrcount2 = arrcount - 1;
                LoginUser(acc_id_input, password_input, uaccounts, arrcount2);
            }





public static void LoginUser(int account_id, String password, Banking[] uaccounts, int arrcount) {
        boolean found = false;
        int accIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrcount - 1; i++) {
            if ((uaccounts[i].accid == account_id) && (uaccounts[i].password.equals(password))) {
                found = true;
                accIndex = i;
                break;
            } else {
                found = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Time to learn how to debug

Comment: What if you remove the minus one here? `for (int i = 0; i < arrcount - 1; i++) {`

Comment: try to use equal() instead of == to compare string

Comment: Your ```arrcount``` is always behind by 1

Comment: You need to declare bankAccount Array Globally , In your code,it's scope is limited to that function only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done few change in above code and it is working fine. 
I have to use Math.random() instead of RendomInt().
And I have used useraccounts.length insteadof arcount variable.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banking[] uaccounts;
        uaccounts = new Banking[100]; // setting up array
        int arrcount = 0; // setting counter for array
        int menu = 1; // Creating a variable to loop menu
        while (menu == 1) { // Creating the loop for the menu
            System.out.println("|=================================================|"); 
            System.out.println("|                                                 |");
            System.out.println("|                     MAIN MENU                   |");
            System.out.println("|  1. Create Account (BANK MANAGER RESTRICTED)    |");
            System.out.println("|  2. Check Account Balance                       |");
            System.out.println("|  3. Deposit Into Account                        |");
            System.out.println("|  4. Withdraw From Account                       |");
            System.out.println("|  5. Quit                                        |");
            System.out.println("|                                                 |");
            System.out.println("|=================================================|");

            int uinput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select an option from above(1 - 4):"));
            if (uinput == 1) { // initiating menu option 1
                String full_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter clients full name:"); // creating some
                                                                                                    // variables
                String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the clients address:");
                String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the clients password:");
                int accid = (int) Math.random();// t(100000, 999999);
                System.out.println("Customers Account ID:" + accid);
                double balance = Double
                        .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the client's starting balance:"));
                uaccounts[arrcount] = new Banking(full_name, address, accid, balance, password); // creating objectg in
                                                                                                    // array
                arrcount = arrcount + 1; // adding to counter for next time

            }
            if (uinput == 2) { // initiating menu option 2
                int acc_id_input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account ID:"));
                String password_input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your password:");
                int arrcount2 = arrcount - 1;
                System.out.println("found" + LoginUser(acc_id_input, password_input, uaccounts, arrcount2));
            }

        }
    }

    public static boolean LoginUser(int account_id, String password, Banking[] uaccounts, int arrcount) {
        boolean found = false;
        int accIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < uaccounts.length; i++) {
            if ((uaccounts[i].accid == account_id) && (uaccounts[i].pass.equals(password))) {
                found = true;
                accIndex = i;
                break;
            } else {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```